# mysqli real escape string returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

below is my code and on calling escape_string it returns empty what is the possible problem here. i use php version 5.6.

```
class Database{
    private $mysqli;
    const HOST='localhost';
    const DATABASE='databaseame';
    const USER='user';
    const PASS='password';
    function __construct($root_url) {
        $this->mysqli=new mysqli(Database::HOST,Database::USER,Database::PASS,Database::DATABASE);
    }
    public function escape_string($data){
        $string=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($data);
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, i found my solution. Actually i forgot to give db access to the following user.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change the line

```
mysqli->real_escape_string($data)
```

to

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($data)
```

Comment: That's not true, in OOP mysqli `real_escape_string` is perfectly valid.

Comment: of course I think you should also pass your connection to mysqli_real_escape_string() function:

Comment: Sorry guys, i found my solution. Actually i forgot to give db access to the following user.
In oop we can do $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($data); @MatinHajatdoost